# HTTP Request POST AJAX(JS) Submit Form

Tags: javascript, ajax, vba, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to change from IE automation in VBA to httprequest, I run into some problem when trying to submit form data with an onclick action like function(). The problem is that when onclick() the form data got submitted to another URL under the same domain.

ex. I am looking at webpage www.test.com/asp.net?186848
when I tracked on chrome debugger, the post method is actually submitting data to www.test.com/component/mxAjaxFunctions.cfc?method=init&ajaxcallid=5498_15544XXXXXXX

Summary

1.form on website submitted using button is a onclick function()

2.form is submitted to a different URL, the ID submitted through form is the one that contained in the original URL.

3.part of the new URL contains a randomly generated ID + date

originally i used the following httprequest in vba to get the data, but it doesnt work, the response return the same content.

Then I went to google chrome and use the network logger, the following were the events that actually happened.

1. the form data is submitted to a different URL then the one I was looking at.
   www.test.com/component/mxAjaxFunctions.cfc?method=init&ajaxcallid=5498_15544XXXXXXX
   later on I found out by reading the .JS file from chrome that 5498 after ajaxcallid is a random number and 15544XXX is actually the date.now() from js

2.The form data submitted logged by chrome is the following:

method: init

function: somefunction

id: 123456

statuscontent: actual content that I put in the textbox

I tried to modify the post request with the different URL which doesn't work, and I tried to copy and paste the form data from chrome and it doesn't work, I also tried to change the method of post to init which doesn't work as well.

```
objHTTP.Open "POST", originalURL, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-type",  "application/x-www-form- 
urlencoded"
objHTTP.send("form data")
```

tried

```
objHTTP.Open "POST", newURL, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-type",  "application/x-www-form-                
urlencoded"
objHTTP.send("form data")
```

didn't work

tried

```
objHTTP.Open "INIT", newURL, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-type",  "application/x-www-form-    
urlencoded"
objHTTP.send("form data")
```

didn't work

tried

```
objHTTP.Open "INIT", newURL, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-type",  "application/x-www-form-    
urlencoded"
objHTTP.send("form data copy from chrome")
```

didn't work

tried

```
objHTTP.Open "INIT", originalURL, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-type",  "application/x-www-form- 
urlencoded"
objHTTP.send("form data copy from chrome")
```

didn't work

Comment: What does didn't work mean? Did you get the same error message or unexpected response for all cases?

Comment: Didn't work means I got the same response text.

Comment: I got it figure out already. so the following were what I did to get that httprequest post to work. So I guess what doesn't work is I copied the url directly in my first try, instead using the copied url, I generated a random number + millisecond elapsed since unix date  just like what the js did on the webpage. I were able to post the data which is the same string I copied from google chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I got it figure out already. so the following were what I did to get that httprequest post to work.

I guess what doesn't work the first time is that I copied the url directly, instead using the copied url, I generated a random number + millisecond elapsed since unix date just like what the js did on the webpage. I were able to post the data which is the same string I copied from google chrome.

```
getunixtime = DateDiff("s", "01/01/1970 00:00:00", Now()) & Right(Timer * 
100, 3)
URL = www.test.com/component/mxAjaxFunctions.cfc? 
method=init&ajaxcallid="& cint(rnd*10001) & "_"& getunixtime


objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-type",  "application/x-www-form-    
urlencoded"
objHTTP.send("form data copy from chrome")
```